# Need help selecting an input box using selenium/python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate posting/removing post on Facebook marketplace. I'm currently on the posting portion of the code and I've managed to get all the way to the the page pictured below. I've tried using `find_element(By.XPATH,...)` to click on the title box with no luck. (Code below)

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Title")]').send_keys(title)
```

After some research I found out you could use `get_attribute`, but I'm not sure if I am using it correctly.

```
browser.get('https://facebook.com/marketplace/create/item/')

time.sleep(3)

title = 'Pokemon Rug'

searchtitlebox = browser.find_element(By.ID, ':rr:')

typevalue = searchtitlebox.get_attribute('type')

browser.wait(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value(typevalue, title))

time.sleep(5)
```

After trying the above code I received an error(no such element: Unable to locate element) for the var searchtitlebox, but I'm sure its just the fact the code isn't being used correctly.

Facebook marketplace input boxes I'm trying to click and fill out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** It appears that the attribute `id` is dynamic and keeps changing each time the page is loaded. Sometimes it's `:rr:` and sometimes its `:rs:` and so on. So use a more reliable locator strategy as below.

**Change this code from:**

```
searchtitlebox = browser.find_element(By.ID, ':rr:')
```

**TO:**

```
searchtitlebox = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Title']//following-sibling::input")
```

**Best practice:** Avoid `time.sleep` and use selenium's [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/). Refer below code to locate same element using `ExplicitWaits`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Title']//following-sibling::input")))
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code should select the span element just fine :

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Title")]')
```

but you should note that the span element doesn't support `send_keys()` since the span element is not interactable.

What you can do instead is to select the input then fill it with the value that you want.

For that you have different options :

**Option 1:** Select the span element with the previous method then select the next element as following :

```
title_span = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Title")]')

title_input = title_span.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::input')

title_input.send_keys(title)
```

or just :

```
title_input = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Title")]//following-sibling::input')

title_input.send_keys(title)
```

**Warning :** the 'Title' keyword that you are using to select the span element might change depending on the website's current language, check if you are using the right keywords on selecting, if you intend to use this program with multiple languages then I suggest you to look for the other options.

**Option 2:** Directly select the input with it's full XPath by inspecting the element, right click, then copy the full XPath :

```
#your copied XPath here :
input_title_xpath = ".../div/label/div/div/input"

title_input = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, input_title_xpath)

title_input.send_keys(title)
```

**Option 3:** Since you need to fill other inputs aswell, you can select all the available inputs then select the ones that you need based on their index.

For example, let's select all the inputs in the page :

```
input_elements = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
#or
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input")
```

then select the inputs concerned (for example the title input is at index 5, the pricing at 6 and so on...):

```
title_input = input_elements[5]
price_input = input_elements[6]
...
```

finally, fill the inputs :

```
title_input.send_keys(title)
price_input .send_keys(price)
...
```

**Tip :** to figure out which index to use, you can print all the input elements like so :

```
for input_element in input_elements:
    print(input_element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

**Note :** you should be aware that this code needs to be maintained since the DOM might change in future updates.

**Warning :** Selecting elements by their ID or Class Name might not be ideal since they keep changing each time the page loads.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been such a headache trying to learn both selenium and python at the same time.

Comment: If you still have any issues relative to this question, could you state them ? otherwise please mark this question as answered